# Django endless pagination on scroll in case of overflowed container

Tags: django

I have the following Django template:

```
<div id = 'test'>
        <form>
            <ul id = 'dialog_list_container'>
                {% include page_template %}
                {% block js %}
                    {{ block.super }}
                    <script src="/static/js/el-pagination.js"></script>
                    <script src="/static/js/el-pagination_on_scroll.js">  
                    </script>
                    <script>
                        $("#test").endlessPaginate({
                            paginateOnScroll: true,
                            paginateOnScrollMargin: 100
                        });
                    </script>
                {% endblock %}
            </ul>
            <div class="ajax_loader"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

`test` is a scrollable element:

```
#test{
   overflow-y: auto;
   height: 500px;
}
```

The problem is that I have still to manually press the `Show more` link in the bottom of paginated list, whereas I would expect new records to be uploaded automatically as I scroll to the bottom of `test`. I guess, the reason is that Django's pagination on scroll triggers in those cases when browser window is scrolled.

Is there any painless way to make Django upload new records in case of a container with css `overflow-y: auto` attribute?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and @jesse answer does not work. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.endlessPaginate` binds to the entire page. If you want to focus on one element, you need to target that element specifically:

```
$("#test").endlessPaginate({
    paginateOnScroll: true,
    paginateOnScrollMargin: 20
});
```

P.S. the standard for ids (and classes) is hyphens not underscores: `#dialog-list-container`

Comment: Try moving your javascript to the bottom of the page, and wrapping your script in `$(document).ready(function() { /* CODE HERE */ });`.

Comment: Well, [this](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/javascript.html#manually-selecting-what-to-bind) is the library reference for what you want to accomplish. Have you tried inspecting the network traffic as you're scrolling to see if it's making the AJAX calls?

Comment: Ok that changes it. You need to bind it to `#test` then, since that's the container that actually gets scrolled.

Comment: Is this only vertical scrolling or can this work for horizontal scrolling also?

Comment: Although my code does not work, I still do accept this answer, because I feel the problem is deeply hidden in my JS code which is beyond the scope of the provided code snippet. I will update the question as I fix it